# How to have option of CAMERA in wkWebView xcode9 swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, wkwebview, filechooser

I created a site in php Laravel that I try to put in a mkWebView of xCode. I find sources on the internet to do it in a simple way.

```
`override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = URL(string:"http://davidwalsh.name/demo/iphone-camera.php")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    _ = myWebView?.load(myRequest)
}`
```

On my website html, i put a filechooser:

```
`<input type="file" accept="image/* capture=camera" name="files1" id="files1" style="display:none" capture="camera" capture camera>`
```

When I want to send an image to my input .. i have only 2 choice: Photo Library or Browse File.
I would like the option of the camera. but I do not find any information on this subject.

In the Safari browser, it works very well, but in my wkWebView not really.

Can anyone help me on this subject?

Comment: I use accept="image/*" and get all three options

Comment: Also have you got "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" setup in your Info.plist

Comment: in wkWebView?!? ... i try this option ... and also 2 options :(